# Problem with tikz-cd diagram

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I was doing this diagram:

```
\[\begin{tikzcd}
    (g\circ f)^{*} E \arrow[dd,bend right]     \arrow[drr,bend left]\\
    g^{*}(f^{*}E) \arrow[d] \arrow[r] & f^{*}E \arrow[d] \arrow[r] & E \arrow[d]\\
    X \arrow[r,"f"] & Y \arrow[r,"g"] & Z 
\end{tikzcd}\]
```

But the arrow [dd,bend right] is too close to one node. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a degree to the `bend` option in order to increase or decrease the curve. So if you write `\arrow[dd,bend right=60]`, you'll obtain this:

[image: example image]